# Filtering GridView on button Click on basis of Dropdownlist and Textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

The requirement which I need is. I want to filter and show the records in `GridView` on button click depending upon the data which I want.

For EX:- I have a `dropdownlist` and `Textbox` in which I will select the data which I want to *filter* then onClick of Button the related data will be shown in the Gridview.

**Please Note**:- The `Dropdownlist`, `Textboxes` and `Button` all are *Outside* the Gridview.

I tried the code from [Here](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Filter-GridView-Records-using-DropDownList-in-HeaderTemplate-Header-Row-in-ASPNet.aspx) but it was not actually what I wanted. Have a look at my code below.

**ASPX**

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblProject" runat="server" Text="Project Name">Project Name</asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProjectName" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblFrmDate" runat="server" Text="From Date">From Date</asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="TxtIndate" runat="server" maxlength="20" type="text" style="text-align: right;
                    width: 75px" readonly="readonly" />
                <cc3:Calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server" CultureName="en-GB" DatePickerImagePath="Images/icon2.gif"
                    DatePickerMode="true" TextBoxId="TxtIndate">
                </cc3:Calendar>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblToDate" runat="server" Text="To Date">To Date</asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="txtOutDate" runat="server" maxlength="20" type="text" style="text-align: right;
                    width: 75px" readonly="readonly" />
                <cc3:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" CultureName="en-GB" DatePickerImagePath="Images/icon2.gif"
                    DatePickerMode="true" TextBoxId="txtOutDate">
                </cc3:Calendar>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Width="100" Text="Search" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="grdData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Also See the **CS code**:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        fillProject();
    }
    grdData.Visible = false;
}
private void fillProject()
{
   // dt.Clear();
    ObjPriDaAdp = new OracleDataAdapter("select distinct Project_id, PROPERTY_NAME Project_name  from xxcus.XXACL_PN_PROJBUILD_V order by PROPERTY_NAME", ObjPriCon);
    ObjPriDaAdp.Fill(dt);
    ddlProjectName.DataTextField = "Project_name";
    ddlProjectName.DataValueField = "Project_id";
    ddlProjectName.DataSource = dt;
    ddlProjectName.DataBind();
    ddlProjectName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--- Select ---", "0"));
}
```

Please suggest how to proceed in these case. May be I am not able to start with these:-

Also, I want to show `Date`, `ProjectName`, `VehicleNO` `TimeIn`, `TimeOut` Columns in the gridview

Comment: you try with RowFilter on gridview atfer bind grid

Comment: @HiralNayak: Give me some start as I m bit confused

Comment: please share the code of grid binding

Comment: @HiralNayak: I haven't written the code for grid binding. Becoz the data which i want to display in the grid are from different table

Comment: then how you show the grid ?

Comment: I need to show on the basis of data entered into the dropdownlist and textbox and then onclick of button display the data into the grid

Comment: means that data not comming from the database ? table value set in the grid ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82347/discussion-between-nad-and-hiral-nayak).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IN CS Page

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string query = "SELECT T1.Project_Id,T2.Project_name,T1.Vehicle_No,T1.Creation_date,T1.Time_In,T1.Time_Out FROM   XXCUS.XX_SUPINV T1 INNER JOIN XXACL_PN_PROJBUILD_V T2 ON T1.Project_Id = T2.Project_id WHERE  Project_Id = '"+ ddlProjectName.SelectedValue +"' AND Creation_date BETWEEN Convert(datetime,'"+lblFrmDate.Text+"') AND Convert(datetime,'"+lblToDate.Text+"')"
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        grdData.DataSource = dt;
        grdData.DataBind(); 
}
```

AND in ASPX Page

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
    CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="PROPERTY NAME" DataField="PROPERTY_NAME" SortExpression="PROPERTY_NAME">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Vehicle No" DataField="Vehicle_No" SortExpression="Vehicle_No">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Creation date" DataField="Creation_date" SortExpression="Creation_date">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Time In" DataField="Time_In" SortExpression="Time_In">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Time Out" DataField="Time_Out" SortExpression="Time_Out">
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I want to display the grid on button click otherwise on pageload it should be hidden. For this Do I have to make any changes

Answer (score 0):

on your button "btnSubmit" click event hold the value of textbox and dropdownlist  then pass that value to the sql query like:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //connection
            string query = "select * from tablename where Projectname like "+ddlProjectName.SelectedValue+"%";// this is an sample query change as per your requirement
             SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query,connection);
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
             da.Fill(dt);
             grdData.DataSource =dt;
             grdData.DataBind(); 
        }
```

here is one link may help out more:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/searching-records-from-database-and-display-in-gridview-usin/

Comment: I tried with my query but it is giving me datetime error. Query: `SELECT Project_Id,Vehicle_No, Creation_date, Time_In, Time_Out FROM XXCUS.XX_SUPINV WHERE Project_Id = '" + ddlProjectName.SelectedValue + "' AND Creation_date BETWEEN Convert(datetime,'" + lblFrmDate.Text + "') AND Convert(datetime,'" + lblToDate.Text + "')"`

Comment: As per your codeing the date are in textbox so change it to:
`SELECT Project_Id,Vehicle_No, Creation_date, Time_In, Time_Out FROM XXCUS.XX_SUPINV WHERE Project_Id = '" + ddlProjectName.SelectedValue + "' AND Creation_date BETWEEN Convert(datetime,'" + TxtIndate.Text + "') AND Convert(datetime,'" + txtOutDate.Text + "')"`

Comment: Then use TO_DATE instead of CONVERT
`SELECT Project_Id,Vehicle_No, Creation_date, Time_In, Time_Out FROM XXCUS.XX_SUPINV  WHERE Project_Id = '" +ddlProjectName.SelectedValue + "' AND Creation_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('" + TxtIndate.Text + "','YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE('" + txtOutDate.Text + "','YYYY-MM-DD')`